# Should entities have behavior or not?

Tags: oop

Should entities have behavior? or not?

Why or why not?

If not, does that violate Encapsulation?

Comment: In what context do you mean entities? ORM-based entities or standalone domain objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your entities do not have behavior, then you are not writing object-oriented code. If everything is done with getters and setters and no other behavior, you're writing procedural code.

A lot of shops [say they're practicing SOA](http://moffdub.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/soa-is-not-an-excuse-to-write-procedural-java/) when they keep their entities dumb. Their justification is that the data structure rarely changes, but the business logic does. This is a fallacy. There are plenty of patterns to deal with this problem, and they don't involve reducing everything to bags of getters and setters.

Answer (score 8):

Entities should not have behavior. They represent data and data itself is passive.
I am currently working on a legacy project that has included behavior in entities and it is a nightmare, code that no one wants to touch.

You can read more on my blog post: [**Object-Oriented Anti-Pattern - Data Objects with Behavior**](http://trumaze.blogspot.com/2011/02/test-post.html) .

### [Preview] Object-Oriented Anti-Pattern - Data Objects with Behavior:

---

**Attributes and Behavior**

Objects are made up of attributes and behavior but Data Objects by definition represent only data and hence can have only attributes. Books, Movies, Files, even IO Streams do not have behavior. A book has a title but it does not know how to read. A movie has actors but it does not know how to play. A file has content but it does not know how to delete. A stream has content but it does not know how to open/close or stop. These are all examples of Data Objects that have attributes but do not have behavior. As such, they should be treated as dumb data objects and we as software engineers should not force behavior upon them.

---

**Passing Around Data Instead of Behavior**

Data Objects are moved around through different execution environments but behavior should be encapsulated and is usually pertinent only to one environment. In any application data is passed around, parsed, manipulated, persisted, retrieved, serialized, deserialized, and so on. An entity for example usually passes from the hibernate layer, to the service layer, to the frontend layer, and back again. In a distributed system it might pass through several pipes, queues, caches and end up in a new execution context. Attributes can apply to all three layers, but particular behavior such as save, parse, serialize only make sense in individual layers. Therefore, adding behavior to data objects violates encapsulation, modularization and even security principles.

---

Code written like this:

```
book.Write();  
book.Print();   
book.Publish();  
book.Buy();  
book.Open();   
book.Read();  
book.Highlight();  
book.Bookmark();  
book.GetRelatedBooks();
```

can be refactored like so:

```
Book book = author.WriteBook();  
printer.Print(book);  
publisher.Publish(book);  
customer.Buy(book);  
  
reader = new BookReader();   
  
reader.Open(Book);   
  
reader.Read();  
reader.Highlight();  
reader.Bookmark();  
  
librarian.GetRelatedBooks(book);
```

What a difference natural object-oriented modeling can make! We went from a single monstrous Book class to six separate classes, each of them responsible for their own individual behavior.

This makes the code:

- easier to read and understand because it is more natural
- easier to update because the functionality is contained in smaller encapsulated classes
- more flexible because we can easily substitute one or more of the six individual classes with overridden versions.
- easier to test because the functionality is separated, and easier to mock

Comment: Entities are not Data Objects, A reader could easily be an entity in your refactored example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of entity they are -- but the term "entity" implies, to me at least, business entities, in which case they should have behavior.

A "Business Entity" is a modeling of a real world object, and it should encapsulate all of the business logic (behavior) and properties/data that the object representation has in the context of your software.

Answer (score 0):

If you're strictly following MVC, your model (entities) won't have any inherent behavior.  I do however include whatever helper methods allow the easiest management of the entities persistence, including methods that help with maintaining its relationship to other entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on exposing your entities to the world, you're better off (generally) keeping behavior off of the entity.  If you want to centralize your business operations (i.e. ValidateVendorOrder) you wouldn't want the Order to have an IsValid() method that runs some logic to validate itself.  You don't want that code running on a client (what if they fudge it.  i.e. akin to not providing any client UI to set the price on an item being placed in a shopping cart, but posting a a bogus price on the URL. If you don't have server-side validation, that's not good!  And duplicating that validation is...redundant...DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Another example of when having behaviors on an entity just doesn't work is the notion of lazy loading.  Alot of ORMs today will allow you to lazy load data when a property is accessed on an entities.  If you're building a 3-tier app, this just doesn't work as your client will ultimately inadvertantly try to make database calls when accessing properties.

These are my off-the-top-of-my-head arguments for keeping behavior off of entities.